# Adding elements to tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, nodes

I have a binary tree and I'm trying to add elements

the problem is if I have and input like `5 5 6 6 9 0 0 2 -1` in the tree are added only `5 6 9 0 2` (I use -1 to stop adding elements)

I tried changing the condition `if(nodeToAdd.data < node.data)` in `if(nodeToAdd.data <= node.data)` but this didn't helped, I tried different conditions, but nothing, every time I got a stack overflow.

What I need to change so I could add two, three or n-times the same number? Any ideas?

Solved the problem, now everything work perfectly)

```
private Node traverseAndAddNode (Node node, int data){

    if(node==null)return new Node(data);

    if(data <= node.data){

       node.leftChild=traverseAndAddNode(node.leftChild, data);

    }else if(data > node.data){
        node.rightChild=traverseAndAddNode(node.rightChild, data);
    }

    return node;

}
```

Comment: Stack overflows are likely a sign of infinite recursion. That means you are never getting to the bottom of your tree. This likely indicates that you have a loop in the tree (some node is pointing further up the tree). Without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to diagnose but I would suggest using a debugger to step through a traversal and see why it is not terminating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your code on my tree. Looks like it works.

```
private Node put(Node i, Key key, Value value) {
    if (i == null) return new Node(key, value, 1);

//      int compare = key.compareTo(i.key);
//      if (compare < 0) i.left = put(i.left, key, value);
//      else if(compare > 0) i.right = put(i.right, key, value);
//      else i.value = value;
//      
//      //update N while unwinding stack
//      i.N = size(i.left) + size(i.right) + 1;
    int compare = key.compareTo(i.key);
    if (compare < 0) {
        if (i.left == null) i.left = new Node(key, value, 1);
        else put(i.left, key, value);
    }
    if (compare >= 0) {
        if (i.right == null) i.right = new Node(key, value, 1);
        else put(i.right, key, value);
    }       
    return i;
}



    //main
    BST<String, Integer> bst = new BST<>();
    String[] s = {"S", "S", "E", "E", "X", "A", "R", "C", "H", "M"};
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        bst.put(s[i], i);   
    }   
    for(String key: bst.keys()) System.out.print(key + " "); // levelordered
```

ouput: S E S A E X C R H M

Answer (score 0):

Currently your method does nothing if `nodeToAdd.data == node.data` because both `if` conditions fail. You likely want:

```
if (nodeToAdd.data < node.data) {
    ...
else {
    ...
}
```

In this case equal nodes will be inserted to the right. If you want them inserted to the left then make the `if` condition `<=`.

None of that explains the stack overflow you mentioned but that is possibly an unrelated bug. I note that your code relies on the node being added having null children. I suggest that you explicitly assert this to ensure no loops are added to your tree in this method. They could well be added elsewhere.

```
assert nodeToAdd.leftChild == null;
assert nodeToAdd.rightChild == null;
```